# prototype.registerCallback is not a function in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I've try to use core-icon and layout element. 
When I import core-icons.html, there's some error..

```
Uncaught TypeError: prototype.registerCallback is not a function
```

and there is any element display on the page.

What should I do to fix it.
- Using Polymer 0.9 and Elements (0.5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Core Elements are not compatible with Polymer 0.9. Use iron-elements instead.

Answer (score 6):

So I got the same error when I started using version 1.0 of Polymer. 
Apparently I was using old syntax.

version 0.5 syntax:

```
Polymer('shape-menu',{
  shapes: ['a'],
  ...
```

version 1.0 syntax:

```
Polymer({
  is:"shape-menu",
  shapes: ['a'],
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

During upgrade from very old Polymer to Polymer v1.7.0 I received this same error.  To fix I noticed that I had accidentally migrated a function into the "properties" section rather than as a sibling to the "properties".

Broken:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-comp',
    properties: {
      myprop: 'my value',
      myfunction: function(){
         ...
      },
    },
});
</script>
```

Fixed:

```
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-comp',
    properties: {
      myprop: 'my value',
    },
    myfunction: function(){
         ...
    },
});
</script>
```

Even though this question is marked as answered I thought this alternate fix might be useful to someone having this error for the same reason I did.