# polymer-micro.html error:prototype.registerCallback is not a function despite of no use of iron or core element

Tags: angularjs, polymer

I am using **polymer 1.0.8** with angularjs through [this](https://github.com/eee-c/angular-bind-polymer) library.and i am getting error

```
Uncaught TypeError: prototype.registerCallback is not a function
```

tried solutions mentioned in [this](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1814) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431606/prototype-registercallback-is-not-a-function-in-polymer) link

**Note:** m not using any paper elements.

**Note:** no core or iron elements are used.m working on much simple example as a beginner.

but still m getting this error and no custom polymer element is working.please help me here.......

Comment: Considering that the last update to that library was 6 months ago, and Polymer 1.0 dropped a little over 2 months ago, it's quite possible there is some incompatibility between the two. Much of the 0.5-0.8 Polymer code (which this was most likely built for) will not work with Polymer 1.0.

Comment: When you see this error, are you in the web console? If so, try to expand the error and see what it is trying to call?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the reason behind it but i fixed this just by removing element's name from definition.

```
 Polymer("x-double",{
  properties:{});
```

to this

```
 Polymer({
  properties:{});
```

may be version's problem or something else...........